# TSX: Read props of children and grandchildren

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am trying to create a wrapping component that would create tabs for me in React (using typescript) and I found some difficulties I can't absolve.

I think I'm in this mess, because I have this requirement, that if we chose to remove the tabbed display, and just have the children on their own, that would still have to be semantically and logically correct and rendered in a non tabular way.

So, the wrapping component is expecting only children. No props, no nothing, just children. The wrapping component is called TabBar and I'm passing in some children:

```js
    <TabBar>
       <section>
          <h2>
              <button>
                 Tab title
              </button>
          </h2>
          <div>
               Content
          </div>
      </section>
    </TabBar>
```

The example above recieves the section as a child.

If I log out the children, I get an array of length 1, which has props, and children, and those have children and so on.

This is an example of the children I receive if I console.log the example above:

```
[
        {
            type: "section",
            props: {
                children: [
                    {
                        type: "h2",
                        props: {
                            props: {
                                children: "Tab title"
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        type: "div",
                        props: {
                            children: "Content"
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    ]
```

Now what I need to do, is to somehow access the props of children and their grandchildren a couple levels deep.

If I console log out ~~look away this is horrid, and only a proof of concept~~:
`console.log(children[0].props.children[0].props.children.props.children);`

I get what I would expect: "Tab title".

problem is , that according to VS code, `children[0].props`

`Property 'props' does not exist on type 'string | number | {} | ReactElement<any, string | ((props: any) => ReactElement<any, string | ... | (new (props: any) => Component<any, any, any>)> | null) | (new (props: any) => Component<...>)> | ReactNodeArray | ReactPortal'.
  Property 'props' does not exist on type 'string'.`

How could I tell typescript that yes... props is there, stop freaking out?

Comment: Parents are not supposed to access props of their grandchildren. Parents pass props to their direct children. Children have access to props their parents pass to them. Why do you need access to the grandchildrens' props?

Comment: Case 1: The section, the button, the div  - all those children are displayed on their own. So they just being added to the dom normally.

Comment: And so you want to access their props because...? When you say access, do you mean you want to pass props from the parent to the grandchildren? What do you mean by "access props"?

Comment: Case 2: The section the button the div, will be added as children to the TabBar. So the tab bar picks up all those props and and renders them in its own tab optimised dom, adding the necessary aria roles and ids to make the tabbed interface work.

Comment: The TabBar doesnt pick up any props. You said the TabBar doesnt have props. If you're rendering components as children of the TabBar, you can pass props straight to them. What do you mean the TabBar picks up props?

Comment: The tab bar can pick up props of their children. Could you please elaborate on this: `Parents are not supposed to access props of their grandchildren. ` Why not?

Comment: In the case of a self closing child component, the parent would not have access to the children of the child component. The way you are logging the children of children of children, I assume you want to get around this by accessing props of grandchildren regardless of whether they are contained within self closing children. If you want to PASS props to children of NON self closing children, then this is fine.